# Why do I have this error when I run the "php artisan" command?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, phpmyadmin

I have a problem with artisan / composer, when I try to run for example: "php artisan" or perform a migration like: "php artisan make: migration" I get this error:

SQLSTATE [42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table

[image]

[image]

Comment: check the database, whether the `intranet` database have `roles` table

Comment: I guess you are setting up your project , and you have relation in table  ?

Comment: I deleted the database because I was having problems with artisan, and so start again from 0, the database "intranet" is empty, the problem comes when I execute some command related to artisan:
-php artisan
-php artisan migrate
-etc...

I do not know what is happening

Comment: Check the order of your migration file and you will get the idea, it is a dependency problem, as you are trying to create a table that depends on column of another table, which is not created at this moment.

Comment: did you work in appserviceprovider if yes then share related code ?

Answer (score 0):

No answer / solution was valid, in the end I deleted everything, and returned to several older versions, it seems that the error came from some part of Laravel's code.

Thank you all.